# Storing and appending html in angular.js

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I'm working on a simple hobby blog for fun, and as a portfolio booster, but I'm hitting an unexpectedly difficult wall with how to manage the text of blog posts as html.

1. When I save the text of a blog post as a text value in the post's designated object, I have to do all kinds of escaping on the apostrophes, and the double quotes are giving me trouble as well.
2. The text is not recognized as HTML, so image files I insert into the blog text aren't recognized(either using img src or ng-src).
3. I could solve this by manually inputting everything into the html of course, but I want to make something dynamic and painless to update.

potential solutions I'm trying:

1. Jquery: manipulate the dom of one html file somehow, where I store a nice html-formatted text for each article with a reference id as the title of the article, and extract each article text and append it as part of the ng-repeat series.
2. Deal with the escaped slashes and find out how to get the inner html recognized as HTML when it's rendered on the page.
3. Doing things "The Angular way" would be desirable. I know ng-include allows you to pull in other html files, but I need to pull a specific element of another file out; I don't want to make an html file for each article's text (or do I?).

I'm mainly working and testing this on my WAMP localhost right now, if that makes a big difference. Here you can see the code/display on codepen:     http://codepen.io/jbreasor/pen/qdebLL.

```
 var news =[
 {title: 'Eyes without a Face:   Horror and Liberation', text: '<p>abc <img src="http://www.hercampus.com/sites/default/files/2014/10/05/Sweet-puppy-sitting.jpg"></p>', type:"review",image:"http://images.popmatters.com/misc_art/d/dvd-eyeswithoutface-650.jpg"},

 {title:'The Psychedelic Comics of Grant Morrison',text:"how do you do", type:"article",image:"http://comicsastonish.files.wordpress.com/2013/09/the-filth-panels.jpg"},

 {title:"MUGEN: A Customizable Fighter with No Copyright Worries",text:"testing 1 2 3", type:"bump", image:"http://fc00.deviantart.net/fs71/i/2012/150/3/b/shaq_vs_spongebob_by_pershon0-d51oiuf.png"},

 {title:"Lifted-1: spaze jazz",text:"live easygoing jazz mixed with drowsy, playful synth sounds that would be familiar to fans of vaporwave",type:"bump",image:"http://p-a-n.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/PAN-61-Lifted-_-front_web.jpg"
 }
 ];
```

I think the reason this is so confusing to me is that I have too many options! If anybody could at least point me in the best direction it would make my day.

Comment: 3. You probably do. Why not? It sounds like that is exactly your usecase, you have a bunch of scaffolding around the article and then you want to pull in each article page. Also, don't count jquery as an option, don't even use jquery, it will hinder your learning of angular.

Comment: not sure where all the escaping problems are, especially if you are using `json_encode` on the data which does escaping for you

Comment: @erik honn I guess i'ts not bad to have a bunch of short html files in your folder?  I just thought it seemed messy/bad for some reason.

Comment: @charlietfl i'll look into json_encode in the future, thanks

Comment: @JonathanReasor Many small html files is generally not a problem. Something to look out for however is the number of requests you will make on each page. Most browser will run multiple requests in paralel within certain limits, if you have a giant list of visible articles you might exceed that limit. It will still work, but the page might load slower since it needs to do so many requests to get each html. You can preload html into a cache, but that requires a lot of setup, so if you need to show a lot of articles at the same time then it might be better to look at some other alternative.